# Make WordPress process admin group comments using $allowedtags

Tags: comments, wp-kses, allowedtags

WP uses `$allowedtags` to limit the set of allowable tags for comments.However, comments from administrators are unfiltered.

What's the easiest way to ensure admin comments are also constrained to the tags contained in `$allowedtags`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`kses_init`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4/wp-includes/kses.php#L1407) is hooked onto the `init` hook with default priority, and (after first removing any of the kses filters) adds filters which strip out tags ([`wp_filter_post_kses`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4/wp-includes/kses.php#L1307) for posts and [`wp_filter_kses`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4/wp-includes/kses.php#L1279) for comments) if the user does not have the capability 'unfiltered_html'.

Since the capability determines whether or not the user can post 'unfiltered_html' comments *and* posts - you probably don't want to just remove that capability.

Instead, hook onto `init`, *after* `kses_init`, say with priority 20, and re-add the filters which strip out tags not in the `$allowedtags` whitelist:

```
add_action('init','wpse56687_filter_everyones_comments',20);
function wpse56687_filter_everyones_comments(){
      add_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wp_filter_kses' );
}
```

Comment: Great - thanks Stephen - that works exactly as needed.